# UnsatisfiedLinkError: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, java-native-interface, google-glass

I'm writing a Google Glass application. I'm using a third-party library that consists of some assets (and instructions to place them in the assets/ dir), some jars (and instructions to place them in the libs/ dir) and a .so (and instructions to place it in libs/armenabi-v7a/).

When I run the application, I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError, it appears the .so isn't being included. Unzipping the apk corroborates this, I don't see the .so anywhere there.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load nameofsofile_jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.package.demo-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.package.demo-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:529)
        at <Calls inside the external library>
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'prebuilt-libs'
 }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.demo"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: new File(buildDir, 'libs'), include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('src/main/libs/jarone.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/jartwo.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/jarthree.jar')
}
```

How do I get it to include the .so?

Answer (score 2):

By default in Android Studio, you .so files should be placed in `src/main/jniLibs/` rather than `src/main/libs/`. I don't see a reason for you to change this, but it is possible with the following code added to the `android{}` part of your `build.gradle` file.

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
}
```